# При нажатии на якорную ссылку, переходить по ней, и менять выпадающий список

Tags: javascript, css, form, button, выпадающий-список

Есть 4 кнопки — "Заказать сейчас" (4 разных цвета позиции). При нажатии на любую кнопку, переходим к форме заказа. Там есть выпадающий список (выбор цвета), цвет по умолчанию (допустим синий), но карточек 4 (4 разных цвета соответственно). Как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки, под карточкой с красным цветом, мы опускались вниз к форме, и в выпадающем списке менялся цвет на красный соответственно ?

---

[image: выпадающий список]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: или дайте скриншот больше, или покажите уже написанный код, или сформулируйте четче вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Добавь [дата-атрибут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) с цветом к пункту списка (чтобы окрашивать в него после клика) и дата-атрибут с id нужной карточки, для карточек тоже data-id завести.
После того, как верстка загрузилась на страницу ([load_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)), тебе нужно вычислять [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) для каждой карточки и где-то в js сохранять (например, в массиве или объекте). При клике на кнопку смотришь id, ищешь нужный элемент в массиве и скроллишь до него через [Window.scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll).

Если вообще не понимаешь с чего начать, разбивай задачу на 2: перекраска и скролл. На codepen.io находишь примеры, адаптируешь под себя.

Чтобы давать более подробные советы, тебе нужно предоставить код. Если ничего нет, то попробуй сделать по описанию, поищи в гугле по ключевым словам. Сделай какую-то демку и возвращайся, переоткрывай вопрос.